# Getting null value of Name Propperty and Saving to Mysql using Spring JPA CrudRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, boot

**I am facing issue regarding getting null value of Name Property and Saving to Mysql using Spring bootJPA using interface CrudRepository. It saved all data to mysql db for all other fields but saving null for Name fields in MySql Db. I am using MySql database.**

**POJO Class**

```
@Entity
public class Registration
{
    @Id
    String username;
    String name;
    String password;
    String email;
    String rollno;
    String dob;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }
    public void setRollno(String rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }
    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Register [username=" + username + ", name=" + name + ", password=" + password + ", email=" + email
                + ", rollno=" + rollno + ", dob=" + dob + "]";
    }
    
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
@Controller
public class RegisterController
{
    @Autowired
    QuizDAO reg;
    @RequestMapping("/Reg")
    public String Reg(Registration register) 
    {
         
        reg.save(register);
        return "Login.jsp";
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.name=eman
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eman
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=eman2022
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**[image: Database table picture is attached in the named column is null value. What is the main issue]**

**QuizDAO Class**

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.klp.JPA.model.Registration;
public interface QuizDAO extends CrudRepository<Registration,String>
{

    
}
```

Comment: Can  you add the QuizDAO as well.

Comment: @Tris, I posted QuizDAO Class code. Will you help me ?

Comment: Please share your payload.  Also, just as a point of security, you should not store the raw password, store a hash of it using one of the available `PasswordEncoders`

Comment: Not a issue woth password.Getting this value name is null by accepeting this at @Controller class.[username=eman2022, name=null, password=3454363920, email=faisal.iqbalgcs123@gmail.com, rollno=BSIT-F13-M20, dob=2022-12-1

Comment: @Faisal please share the data that you're sending to your endpoint, as it looks like you aren't sending the name field, so it makes sense that it's not being persisted.

Comment: Thanks @lane.maxwell problem is solved. Issue with front end name field.

Comment: @Faisal, I'm glad it's working.  I understand that there is not an issue with the persistence of the password. I made the point that you should NOT persist the password; you should persist a hashed version of it; it's a massive security hole to persist the raw password value.